# Accurate time on Android

Tags: java, android

Is there an way to get a time very precisely in Android . I found ntp is the best way to do this ..is there any existing library is there in android for taking ntp time .? 
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

According to the Docs:
Returns the current system time in milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the android devices time as @Kushwaha suggested should be fine. The device will keep syncing usually over the internet or via the mobile network provider so getting the device time should be accurate without directly contacting an ntp server.